# Enquiry on WDI API URL design

Tags: url

I was reading the WDI API documentation , and I saw an example there where it explained what the API example meant.

http://api.worldbank.org/v2/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD

> To request the indicator GDP (Current US$), use its indicator code, NY.GDP.MKTP.CD:

But my question is, how are we able to know what each of those elements in the code mean? (i.e NY/MKTP/CD)
I tried looking all around the documentation but am lost as to where I can find the definitions. Much help appreciated.